# error MSB4018: The CreateAppHost task failed unexpectedly Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build-error

Whenever I try to build my project I get this error

```
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(424,5): error MSB4018: The "CreateAppHost" task failed unexpectedly.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(424,5): error MSB4018: Microsoft.NET.HostModel.HResultException: 80070002
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(424,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.ResourceUpdater.AddResourcesFromPEImage(String peFile)
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(424,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<CreateAppHost>g__UpdateResources|1()
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(424,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.RetryUtil.RetryOnWin32Error(Action func)
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(424,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.CreateAppHost(String appHostSourceFilePath, String appHostDestinationFilePath, String appBinaryFilePath, Boolean windowsGraphicalUserInterface, String assemblyToCopyResorcesFrom)
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(424,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.CreateAppHost.ExecuteCore()
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(424,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(424,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(424,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

I have tried

- Running visual studio as admin
- Deleting obj and bin folders
- Creating a new project and copying in the old source files

Turning off my anti-virus does work but it is obviously not ideal.

Comment: Can you show how you're calling `EnumDesktopWindows` in your application.

Comment: The exception has nothing to do with EnumDesktopWindows.  Same failure [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/11244), move the project to a directory closer to the root.

Comment: @Hans Passant The project is at C:/Code/CSharp/ProjectFolder, is that really too far from root?

Comment: Ok that is weird. Before removing the calls to EnumDeskWin fixed the issue but now it's still not building. I have tried copying the project closer to root and it now works but I'd rather fix it where it was before if possible.

Comment: Never mind the issue is back, again.

Comment: Temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: That didn't work. :/

Answer (score 2):

I had my project in a Google Drive folder and it worked well until I installed some updates and the "CreateAppHost" error appeared.

Taking the project folder outside Google Drive fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I do have the exact same problem after moving my project into Google Drive.
To clarify: I was always developing in a OneDrive folder without issues. As soon as I moved the project to a Google Drive folder - without changing any code - I got "The "CreateAppHost" task failed unexpectedly".

So yeah, take the project off Google Drive.